# How can I export annotations from a PDF file in Ubuntu?

Tags: pdf, okular

Exchanging academic PDF with some fellas made me think if it was possible to export the annotations and, in case of yet-to-be-published papers, the corrections from those files to a spreadsheet or eventually, a simply text file.

Currently I have been using two PDF viewers: Okular and qpdfview. Qpdfview is lighting fast, but it pays the price for being too simple for those features. In the other hand, Okular is the most complete viewer that I know of in Ubuntu, which unfortunately does not support this feature either. Does anybody know of any program to solve this issue?

Comment: See also this question on super user [How to export comments from a PDF file?](https://superuser.com/q/698811/419414)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will meet your requirements, but an online solution might be https://www.sumnotes.net (I have no affiliation with the company).

Comment: Indeed it does what I asked for, but it is not a Ubuntu software. The tool does actually a quite good job, but the extracted file is not so well sorted. Although I didn't say in my post either, I would also go rather for a free tool. I have just signed up to their website, and yet I have to upgrade my account to extract all possible annotations. But so far it is in fact the best tool that I've been shown.